# Spring boot war file does not work on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I added spring boot to a existing webapp. When i run the command

```
java -jar -Denvironment.type=dev myfile.war
```

Every things goes fine. But if I deploy on tomcat, for some reason a get a very big exception.

```
Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
```

I am using mongodb and I do not have any datasource configured on my application context. I also extended SpringBootServletInitializer

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdminApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
    return builder.sources(AdminApp.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AdminApp.class, args);
}
}
```

Any clue what can it be?

My properties file

```
database.url=localhost
database.port=27017
database.name=dbname
database.username=admin
database.password=admin
```

Update: I also have this class the says which property file should be used.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application-${environment.type}.properties")
public class PropertyWithJavaConfig {

@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
}

}
```

Comment: You probably have `spring-data-jpa` on your classpath.

Comment: Where do you keep your application.properties?

Comment: The application.properties is kept on the resource folder and its been loaded. I did not override any spring properties and also there is no jpa or hibernate on the classpath. Its weird because just fail if i deploy on a normal tomcat. On the embedded tomcat from spring-boot works just fine.

Comment: any chance you have another application.properties file lying around somewhere in the current directory when you run with `java -jar`?

Comment: I have 3. But they are all called. application-dev, application-stage, application-live. They are all inside of the war file. And no, there is no other property file around the directory

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown in DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName() method. Find below the source code of the same from spring distribution:

```
if (!StringUtils.hasText(driverClassName)) {
    throw new BeanCreationException(
        "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type "
            + this.embeddedDatabaseConnection
            + ". If you want an embedded "
            + "database please put a supported one on the classpath.");
}
```

Spring throws this error when spring.datasource.driverClassName property is empty. So to fix this error, make sure that the application.properties is in the classpath.

Comment: `application.properties` does not have to be on the classpath, it just has to be somewhere in scope for the particular application.

Comment: What do you mean by "scope for the particular application"? Btw, where have you placed the application.properties file?

Comment: In can be in any of these places: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files and that's only application.properties, you can externalize configuration in many other ways, http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config

Comment: Ok, where is the properties file stored in your case? and Please share the property file.

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question, I'm just commenting. I have asked the original poster exactly that question, because without knowing where his properties are stored we can't help him. All I said was, your answer is too narrow, application.properties does not have to be on the classpath, and in a setup with an external tomcat, it probably shouldn't be.

Comment: The application.properties is kept on the resource folder and its been loaded. I did not override any spring properties. Its weird because just fail if i deploy on a normal tomcat. On the embedded tomcat from spring-boot works just fine

Answer (score 0):

So, after digging a lot on the dependencies I noticed that I had spring-orm and spring-jdbc even though I was not using. I removed them and everything worked fine for embedded and local tomcat.

But I still can not understand why before worked just for embedded tomcat.